# change size of titleview in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to change the size of the titleview in a navigation bar? Some of the titles I want to use are too long to display in the current size, so I want to horizontally expand the titleview. This is what I've tried so far:

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,500,32)];
[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = testView;
```

No matter how big I make the width it stil won't expand beyond a certain point. This is what I see:

[image]

Is there anyway to get around this? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is now easy way to do so. But you can use `UINavigationController`'s method

```
- (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass;
```

to create UINavigationController with custom UINavigationBar.

> Use this initializer to make the navigation controller use your custom
>   bar class.     Passing nil for navigationBarClass will get you
>   UINavigationBar, nil for toolbarClass gets UIToolbar.    The arguments
>   must otherwise be subclasses of the respective UIKit classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Avt. What should I override in my custom navigation bar to expand the title view?

Comment: @connor Difficult to say. I have never did the same thing myself. You can try to paste your current code to customNavigationBar's `- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated;` method.